# Generate heatmap from nested JSON

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap

I am trying to generate a heatmap from the SQUAD v1.1 dataset given [here](https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/dataset/train-v1.1.json).

---

The squad dataset is depicted as follows:

```
Document/
├── Paragraph1/
│   ├── Question
│   ├── Answer1
│   ├── Answer2
│   └── Answer3
├── Paragraph2/
│   ├── Question
│   └── Answer1
```

A document may have multiple paragraph / context(s). Each paragraph (context) may have multiple question and answers. Its depicted [here](https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/dataset/train-v1.1.json).

I am planning to denormalize the JSON into CSV like which may be wrong:

```
Context,Question,Answer
Context1,Question1,Answer1
Context1,Question1,Answer2
Context1,Question2,Answer1
...
```

---

So far I normalized the nested JSON into a CSV file using the below code:

```
import json
import csv

with open(r'SQUAD v1.json') as squad_data_file_handle:
    squad_data = json.load(squad_data_file_handle)

with open('SQUAD_11_CSV.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='UTF-8') as squad_csv_handle:
    writer = csv.writer(squad_csv_handle, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(["Context", "Question", "Answer"])
    for data in squad_data["data"]:
        for paragraph in data["paragraphs"]:
            context = str(paragraph["context"])
            question_answer_pairs = paragraph.get("qas", [])

            for qa_pair in question_answer_pairs:
                    question = str(qa_pair["question"])
                    answers = list(set([str(answer.get("text")) for answer in qa_pair.get("answers", [])]))
                    for answer in answers:
                        writer.writerow([context, question, answer])
```

---

So its generating the CSV as follows (first two rows):

```
Context,Question,Answer
"Super Bowl 50 was an American football game to determine the champion of the National Football League (NFL) for the 2015 season. The American Football Conference (AFC) champion Denver Broncos defeated the National Football Conference (NFC) champion Carolina Panthers 24–10 to earn their third Super Bowl title. The game was played on February 7, 2016, at Levi's Stadium in the San Francisco Bay Area at Santa Clara, California. As this was the 50th Super Bowl, the league emphasized the ""golden anniversary"" with various gold-themed initiatives, as well as temporarily suspending the tradition of naming each Super Bowl game with Roman numerals (under which the game would have been known as ""Super Bowl L""), so that the logo could prominently feature the Arabic numerals 50.",Which NFL team represented the AFC at Super Bowl 50?,Denver Broncos
"Super Bowl 50 was an American football game to determine the champion of the National Football League (NFL) for the 2015 season. The American Football Conference (AFC) champion Denver Broncos defeated the National Football Conference (NFC) champion Carolina Panthers 24–10 to earn their third Super Bowl title. The game was played on February 7, 2016, at Levi's Stadium in the San Francisco Bay Area at Santa Clara, California. As this was the 50th Super Bowl, the league emphasized the ""golden anniversary"" with various gold-themed initiatives, as well as temporarily suspending the tradition of naming each Super Bowl game with Roman numerals (under which the game would have been known as ""Super Bowl L""), so that the logo could prominently feature the Arabic numerals 50.",Which NFL team represented the NFC at Super Bowl 50?,Carolina Panthers
```

---

This is the code I am using to generate heatmap:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv(r"SQUAD_11_CSV.csv")
df = df.pivot("Context", "Question", "Answer")
sns.heatmap(df)
plt.show()
```

So, when I am trying to generate a heatmap, its throwing an exception that:

> `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

So, any tips / pointers to any obvious mistakes on how to generate the heatmap and model the SQUAD JSON data into a perfect CSV will be appreciated.

---

**Update:**

Heatmap must look something like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you hope for the heatmap to actually show?

Comment: @tripleee Whether the data is skewed or balanced

Comment: That's apparently your goal, but what should the plot look like?

Comment: @tripleee this is the kind of Heatmap I am trying to make